# GetSystemIdForPublisher doesn't return unique ID

Tags: windows, winapi, uwp

I use [GetSystemIdForPublisher()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.profile.systemidentification.getsystemidforpublisher?view=winrt-18362) to identify machine IDs. According to the documentation they are unique, but I have a handful of machines which return the same ID. These machines are completely unrelated and have no common history. They are located in different countries and belong to different users. The Windows version of these machines is the latest Windows 1909 `10.0.18363` update.

The documentation clearly states:

> The method will first attempt to use the Trusted Platform Module
>   (TPM), if present, to get an ID. If a TPM is not present, the method
>   will try to get an ID from the Unified Extensible Firmware Interface
>   (UEFI). If neither of these sources is available, this method will
>   return an ID that is backed by the Windows registry. In the case of
>   the Windows registry, the ID will not satisfy all the above
>   guarantees. For example, if a system does not have a TPM or UEFI
>   support, and thus an ID was obtained from the registry, a clean
>   install of Windows will result in a new, different ID being returned.
>   Callers of this method should refer to the Source property of the
>   returned SystemIdentificationInfo to determine where the ID was
>   obtained from in order to understand the guarantees provided.

As far as I can see, none of these statements explain to me what is happening here. Does anyone else have an idea whats going on? Any help is highly appreciated!

**Addendum:**

we got feedback in form of a cpu-z report from 2 persons on 2 different continents with the same machine id:

user A:

```
Mainboard Model Z87M Extreme4 (0x00000444 - 0xECE9B6D4)
UEFI Yes
BIOS Vendor American Megatrends Inc.
BIOS MSG 63-0100-000001-00101111-1xxxx5-Chipset
BIOS Date 12/10/15
Mainboard Vendor 000001
```

user B:

```
Mainboard Model 151-BE-E097 (0x0000025D - 0x0A74C7F0)
UEFI Yes
BIOS Vendor American Megatrends Inc.
BIOS MSG 63-0100-000001-00101111-0XXXX5-Chipset
BIOS Date 09/10/15
Mainboard Vendor 000001
```

both got the same identifier when calling GetSystemIdForPublisher():

```
XlPRXXXlAPXk-yFXXXJUv3-XXXXXXXXXXXXX = [source is UEFI, ]
==> X included for obfuscation
```

We have around 60 customers worldwide whose computers return this exact ID.

Comment: Have you checked the SystemIdentificationInfo.Source property? Were the machines created from a common master?

Comment: Did you evaluate the `Source` property to see, where the IDs came from?

Comment: @SimonMourier I am very sure there is no master they were created from. It's just by coincidence that a few users in different countries showed up with the same ID. Simon, Inspectable Thanks so much, I didn't know the attribute yet. I will update my post asap as I have new info! Thanks again!!

Comment: The source on two of these systems is from UEFI

Comment: Windows stores ids (for licensing mostly) in UEFI NVRam (see values with EAEC226F-C9A3-477A-A826-DDC716CDC0E3 guid here https://oofhours.com/2019/09/02/geeking-out-with-uefi/). If you can boot UEFI on these machines you could check these. I believe this is similar (or a derivate?) to the Device id that you can see in "About your PC" in Windows 10. Do these machines have the same Device Id? You can try that also: https://gist.github.com/Wack0/663dc0a91056cf4431365f77036f3bf3 see if it returns the same id. Do the machine have the same motherboard/model/vendor?

Comment: Thank you so much! I will investigate further

Comment: @SimonMourier I edited my initial question and added some more information

Comment: Have you seen this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180131-00/?p=97945 it says "The value you receive is specific to the publisher specified in your application manifest. If you are a classic Win32 app with no manifest, then the system will use a generic “publisher” that is used for all publisher-less apps." combined with doc that says "On any particular system, all apps by the same publisher will get the same value for this ID (for all users). Conversely, apps by different publishers on the same system will obtain different IDs." Do you have a manifest with a publisher?

Comment: We are a software publisher and use the mentioned function above to retrieve a system unique ID for licencing purposes. So I would expect the ID would *always* return a different ID on different systems

Comment: P.S. Thanks for the hint with the publisher manifest. That indeed seems to be not defined

Comment: You should define it then and test again.

Comment: @HelloWorld Might be a shot in the dark, but if those users are responsible for their own windows installations and they have the same cracked version of windows (and no TPM), you might be getting same results when the source is UEFI.

Comment: I was thinking the same, but two users confirmed that the licenses got legally bought from the Microsoft online store just a few days ago. They didn't back up and still offer help to investigate what can cause it, so no reason at the moment for me to distrust their statements

Comment: you need by self generate unique id (say by `BCryptGenRandom`) and store it in system

Comment: Hi, yes, that's a workaround for the problem. Unfortunately it doesn't explain the cause of the issue. We filed a bugreport to Microsoft

Comment: this api do next - https://mastodon.social/@slipstream/99514497819803181